# How can I avoid using class variables in Ruby

Tags: ruby, class-variables

I have a piece of code that uses class variables. I've read that class variables should generally be avoided in Ruby.

The class variables are `@@cost` and `@@kwh`.

How can I rewrite the following without using class variables?

```
class Device
 attr_accessor :name, :watt

 @@cost = 0.0946

 def initialize(name, watt)
   @name = name
   @watt = watt
 end

  def watt_to_kwh(hours)
    @@kwh = (watt / 1000) * hours
  end

  def cost_of_energy
    puts "How many hours do you use the #{self.name} daily?"
  hours = gets.chomp.to_i
    self.watt_to_kwh(hours)
    daily_cost = @@kwh * @@cost
    montly_cost = daily_cost * 30
    puts "Dayly cost: #{daily_cost}€"
    puts "montly_cost: #{montly_cost}€"
  end
end
```

Comment: Why is `@@kwh` a class variable?

Comment: I believe `montly_cost` should `monty_cost`, assuming  it concerns Monty Python's Flying Circus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@@cost` behaves more like a *constant* (i.e. it won't change during runtime), so you should use one instead:

```
COST = 0.0946
```

`@@kwh` should be an instance variable, since it is used only within the instantiated object, so you could use `@kwh` instead:

```
@kwh = (watt / 1000) * hours
```

And `daily_cost = @@kwh * @@cost` will become:

```
daily_cost = @kwh * COST
```

---

That will avoid the use of class variables, but you could also eliminate `@kwh` altogether since you don't use it anywhere else.

So, instead of:

```
def watt_to_kwh(hours)
  @kwh = (watt / 1000) * hours
end
```

You could just do:

```
def watt_to_kwh(hours)
  (watt / 1000) * hours
end
```

And use it like this in `cost_of_energy` method:

```
def cost_of_energy
  puts "How many hours do you use the #{self.name} daily?"
  hours = gets.chomp.to_i
  daily_cost = watt_to_kwh(hours) * COST
  montly_cost = daily_cost * 30
  puts "Dayly cost: #{daily_cost}€"
  puts "montly_cost: #{montly_cost}€"
end
```

Comment: I've actually to make both instance variables, before posting, but it didn't worked, I was getting an `*': nil can't be coerced into Integer` TypeError. 

Now I see that making `Cost` a local variable is the reason  i'm getting the error. But why? Why `@kwh` works and `@cost` doesn't?

Comment: @johnlock1 How did you set `@cost = 0.0946`? It should be set inside `initialize` method (or any other instance method).

Comment: @gery Ok, so in order to use an instance variable I have to set it inside a method? I haven't understood that, thanks for clearing it out for me!

Comment: @johnlock1 Yes, otherwise it won't be available to the instantiated object.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
class Device
  singleton_class.send(:attr_accessor, :cost_per_kwh)

  def initialize(name, watts)
    @name = name
    @watts = watts
  end

  def daily_cost(hours_per_day)
    self.class.cost_per_kwh * kwh_per_day(hours_per_day)
  end

  def monthly_cost(hours_per_day)
    30 * daily_cost(hours_per_day)
  end

  private

  def kwh_per_day(hours_per_day)
    hours_per_day * @watts / 1000
  end
end
```

`singleton_class.send(:attr_accessor, :cost_per_kwh)` creates a setter and getter for the class instance variable `@cost_per_kwh`.

First, obtain and save the cost per kwh, which will be used in the calculation of cost for all devices of interest.

```
puts "Please enter the cost per kwh in $"    
Device.cost_per_kwh = gets.chomp.to_f
```

Suppose

```
Device.cost_per_kwh = 0.0946
```

Calculate the costs for each device of interest.

```
puts "What is the name of the device?"
name = gets.chomp

puts "How many watts does it draw?"
watts = gets.chomp.to_f
```

Suppose

```
name = "chair"
watts = 20000.0
```

We may now create a class instance.

```
device = Device.new(name, watts)
  #=> #<Device:0x007f9d530206f0 @name="chair", @watts=20000.0>
```

Lastly, obtain hours per days, the only variable likely to change in future calculations of costs for the given device.

```
puts "How many hours do you use the #{name} daily?"
hours_per_day = gets.chomp.to_f
```

Lastly, suppose

```
hours_per_day = 0.018
```

then we may compute the costs.

```
puts "Daily cost: $#{ device.daily_cost(hours_per_day)}"
Daily cost: $0.034056€

puts "Monthly_cost (30 days/month): $#{ 30 * device.daily_cost(hours_per_day) }"
Monthly_cost (30 days/month): $1.0216800000000001
```

Suppose circumstances change<sup>1</sup> and use of the device increases. We need only update hours per day. For example,

```
puts "How many hours do you use the #{name} daily?"
hours_per_day = gets.chomp.to_f
```

Suppose now

```
hours_per_day = 1.5
```

Then

```
puts "Daily cost: $#{ device.daily_cost(hours_per_day)}"    
Daily cost: $2.838

puts "Monthly_cost (30 days/month): $#{ 30 * device.daily_cost(hours_per_day) }"
Monthly_cost (30 days/month): $85.14
```

<sup>1 The election of a new president, for example.</sup>

Comment: Nice! I like `singleton_class` to avoid the (hardcoded) constant.